# How to fix Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, office365

I am trying to send email using Java Mail API from my application. The code I am using is as follows:

```
   private void sendMail(Properties props, String fromEmail, String password, String toEmail, String messageSubject, String messageBody)
    {
        final String username = fromEmail;
        final String pasword = password;
        //props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
        {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username,pasword);
            }
        });
    try 
    {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(toEmail));
        message.setSubject(messageSubject);
        message.setText(messageBody);
        Transport.send(message);
    } 
    catch (MessagingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    }
```

And I have the following properties:

```
{mail.smtp.port=587, mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465, mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory, mail.smtp.auth=true, mail.smtp.host=smtp.office365.com}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
```

The same code was working for `smtp.gmail.com` and I was able to send mails from gmail based emails. Is there any solution for this issue.

Comment: Try to google the error message and you'll find answers.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the Authenticator and just call the [Transport.send method that takes a username and password](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), as described in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 0):

Please set the below in your code

```
message.setHeader("X-Mailer","your application name");
```